# How to use Vagrant & Puppet with https

Tags: apache, ssl, https, vagrant, puppet

I am trying for hours, but I just can't figure it out, how to enable a https connection with vagrant and puppet.

I have a folder files/htdocs which contains different configs-files. Like vhosts. It was a preset, with an empty ssl and empty vhosts_ssl folder. It put my ssl certificate in the ssl folder and my httpd-ssl.conf in the vhosts_ssl folder. Those files where working lokal with my MAMP Webserver.

In the Puppet config I wrote the following:

```
file { "/etc/httpd/vhosts":
    replace => true,
    ensure  => present,
    source  => "/vagrant/files/httpd/vhosts",
    recurse => true,
}

file { "/etc/httpd/vhosts_ssl":
        replace => true,
        ensure => present,
        source  => "/vagrant/files/httpd/vhosts_ssl/httpd-ssl.conf",
}

file { "/etc/httpd/ssl":
        replace => true,
        ensure => present,
        source  => "/vagrant/files/httpd/ssl",
        recurse => true,
}
```

The normal vhosts are working, therefore I thougt I can copy the structure and just enter the new paths for ssl and vhosts_ssl.
But its not working. Maybe you know how to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this configuration?

Comment: No, I just stopped working on this little project.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, but I have no time to test it right know.

Here is the link to the possible solution.
https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache

I will update my Questing/Answere when I tried it.

Comment: This will work, I suppose, but sadly not with my architecture. I need to configurate puppet with those config files, but this link solves the problem through a different way...